# Is "Thank you for listening" for when someone has already listened to you?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

> **Thank you for listening.** I won't take any more of your time.

Is this something you say when someone *has* listened to you, or would you say something like...

> Thank you because you listened.

Comment: It's fine. You thank someone **for** an action, not because of it.

Comment: You can say whatever you want.

Comment: I feel like this question still needs clarification. I took it to be asking "Would 'thank you for listening' be inappropriate *before* someone has listened"? OR possibly "Would 'thank you for listening' still be appropriate even if the person didn't in fact listen?"

Comment: I believe the person is asking this  because they associate "ing-form" with Continuous Aspect. (which is not correct). My guess is that  they are afraid of saying "for listening" because they think it might be interpreted as "I thank you because  you are listening now". Ing-form can be used separately, as a noun (gerund) and in this usage does not inherit the meaning of the Continuous Aspect, so it's absolutely fine to say "Thank you for listening" even when person has already finished listening.

Answer (score 1):

"Thank you for listening." is most often used at the end of a speech or statement, as the example in the question suggests. In this use it is **very** common, a fixed phrase.

It can also be used before the listening takes place, but that is a much less common use. For example:

> A: Please listen to my reasons for this decision.
> B: All right, I'll listen.
> A: Thank you for listening. First of all, I want to ...

or

> I am glad you could all make it today. Thank you for listening to me. My first point is ...

The sentence

> Thank you because you listened.

is much less common, and sounds somewhat odd to my ear. I see no advantages to its use, but I don't see any grammatical errors in it.

Comment: About "thanking before [the action you're thanking them for]": Often people "thank [someone] in advance." This can be reasonable, when the action is absolutely certain to happen, or can be a [passive-aggressive way of making a demand](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/thank-you-in-advance/).